# Compatibility between Flash and Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I had an online game partially developed for me using Flex, by a developer whom I no longer deal with. A new developer (who only develops in Flash) now tells me he has to download Flex in order to build on what's already been built.

Is this correct? Can you not view/import assets and code from Flex to Flash? I thought Flex outputs actionscript, which is Flash's native language. Can anyone please clear up this confusion?

Also, my game will contain 3D animation, use the database connectivity and will eventually be published to mobile platforms.  What is the best program to continue with this project?

Answer (score 1):

Flex is framework that build upon ActionScript, but include new features. To be able to do that, Flex use a specific compiler to generate the swf app from the source code.
Adobe Flash Pro IDE uses Adobe's standard compiler, so it can't compile Flex Projects.

To be able to do so, the developer will need the Apache Flex SDK (free download from Apache website), and preferably a compatible IDE.

Adobe Flash Builder (present in Adobe CS/CC), Flash Develop (free) and JetBrains IntelliJIDEA ($199/$499) are the IDEs I know of that possess Flex integration.

A developer could use a non-compatible IDE with the Flex SDK, but it would make his work considerably harder.

Answer (score 0):

On a very basic level there is no difference.
It is very strange to be used enterprise oriented application framework as Flex for game development.
Probably it's not directly about Flex framework, but about the Adobe's Flash Builder also know as Flex Builder.
It's one of the best Flex/ActionScript IDE's out there (the best - my personal opinion), and it's worth each cent.

About Your second question - Flex is giving much more quality and less times spend on a project than pure ActionScript, anyway there will be practically from none to small benefit (**maybe in some classes oriented to database/server side integration**) in the 3D application as your game is, since it is very unlikely to use some of the Flex application oriented classes.

About Your last question - whatever You prefer - Flash Builder ( Flex Builder ) ( or some IDE alike ) or Flash Professional - everything will be about the developer, and whatever he prefer as tool to build his application.
**Flash Builder** is more beneficial as Application Development Environment oriented to single timeline, preferred usually from the coders.
**Flash Professional** is more oriented as for Multiple Timeline Animation and 2D Game development IDE, preferred usually from the designers.

Building a 3D game, it's most likely to feel no difference between IDE's, so- **let Your developer choose His tools and framework** as I mentioned above.